# How to use str_replace with escape html characters

Tags: php, str-replace, translate

I use str_replace to make cyrillic text form database. Text in database have a html codes like `<br>`, `<b>`,... I use `str_replace` like this:

```
$cir = array("љ", "њ", "е", "р", "т", "з", "у", "и", "о", "п", "ш", "ђ", "а", "с", "д", "ф", "г", "х", "ј", "к", "л", "ч", "ћ", "ж", "џ", "ц", "в", "б", "н", "м", "Љ", "Њ", "Е", "Р", "Т", "З", "У", "И", "О", "П", "Ш", "Ђ", "А", "С", "Д", "Ф", "Г", "Х", "Ј", "К", "Л", "Ч", "Ћ", "Ж", "Џ", "Ц", "В", "Б", "Н", "М");
    $lat = array("lj", "nj", "e", "r", "t", "z", "u", "i", "o", "p", "š", "đ", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "č", "ć", "ž", "dž", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", "Lj", "Nj", "E", "R", "T", "Z", "U", "I", "O", "P", "Š", "Ć", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Č", "Ć", "Ž", "DŽ", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M");
$out = str_replace($cir,$lat,$txt);
return $out
```

in function. But I have a problem. html tags also translated, so I got `<б>`, `<и>`... How to escape html codes from translator?

Comment: You should use an HTML DOM parser to get just the text parts, and do the replacements there.

Comment: Look in [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [that](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse your HTML and change the relevant parts, which is the text not the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only a few html tags in your text, you could do it dirty, that means that you replace tags first, do your translation and bring the tags back afterwards. E.g.

```
$tags = array("<br>","<b>", ...);
$nums = array("<1>","<2>", ...);

$out = str_replace($tags,$nums,$txt);
$out = str_replace($lat,$cir,$out);
$out = str_replace($nums,$tags,$out);
```

Btw: In your given code you are replacing cyrillic letters with latin letters and not vice versa. Therefore I switched it here. Otherwise you shouldn't have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every tag start with "<" and close with ">". I personally will had main text and with a loop will go tru every char and i will have one bool variable which start "true" and change to "false" when i hit a "<", and changes back to true when find ">" char in main string. So after that i will have a if statement for my bool variable and if is true i will replace chars or is it false i will not.